# How Can I open the old version of document uploaded in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint

I could able to download the old version of document in the share point but I can't open itin webUI, how can do that??

Comment: Do you want to download the document using any API? Like powershell?

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Version History" of the document and click on the required version you want to see on the Web UI.

Also do change your Browse File handling property to Permissive.

Central Administration -> Application Management -> Select web application -> Click general settings -> Check Browse File Handling to "Permissive"